# Start Windows Task from Outlook Macro

Tags: .net, outlook, macros, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to run a scheduled Task in Windows Server 2008 from an Outlook Macro?
Background is that it should be possible to start this task on incoming emails with a special subject. The task normally runs every day, but sometimes it should be triggered manually and not everybody has access to the server. Maybe someone has a solution or a better alternative.

**EDIT:** My solution was:

```
Shell ("C:\Windows\System32\SchTasks.exe /run /tn ""ApprovalSupporter""")
```

Thanks to ho1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't remember the exact details, but you should be able to execute a command using `ShellExecute` or something similar and then you can probably just run `Schtasks /RUN` as described in this Technet article: [Schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Edit: Here's a link for [ShellExecute](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00479.htm)